# Why am I not able to upload file with following nodeJS code

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I am trying to learn to upload a file using the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads/'}).single('file'));

app.get('/index.htm', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.htm" );
})

app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.file.name);
   console.log(req.file.path);
   console.log(req.file.type);
   var file = __dirname + "/" + req.file.name;
   console.log("File Name: " file);
   fs.readFile( req.file.path, function (err, data) {
      fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
         if( err ) {
            console.log( err );
            } else {
               response = {
                  message:'File uploaded successfully',
                  filename:req.file.name
               };
            }

         console.log( response );
         res.end( JSON.stringify( response ) );
      });
   });
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

The file is successfully getting uploaded in /uploads directory, however, I am not able to open the file from there. Also, I am unable to print the name of the file when I try `console.log(req.file.name);` I get the output as undefined.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Console output as requested

```
Info: Start process (2:45:28 PM)
Example app listening at http://:::8081
undefined
uploads\3cbe4d0c18a778a9faddc6243c26b26a
undefined
File Name:  undefined
{ message: 'File uploaded successfully', filename: undefined }
Process canceled
Info: End process (2:52:29 PM)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the console output as is?

Comment: Added console output as requested.

Comment: Thanks. it seams that only req.file.path is filled and no other information, you expect here (especially req.file.name is undefined!!).

Comment: Also, the file is not getting uploaded with the original name as you can see from the console output.

Comment: I see. Either fix the file.name or extract the filename from the file.path variable.